# OS X Programmatically Set Default Output Device

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-audio, osx-yosemite

I have been attempting to change which audio device my computer sends sound to. My end goal is to create a program that can make my laptop output to its built-in speakers even when headphones are plugged into the headphone jack.

I stumbled across [this](https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx) project, but the methods it uses (specifically `AudioHardwareSetProperty`) are deprecated. It also just doesn't work (it will say it changed the output device, but sound will still go to my headphones).

CoreAudio seems very poorly documented and I could not find ANY code online that did not use that function. I would go with the deprecated function if it did what I wanted, but it doesn't. I'm unsure weather it's broken or just doesn't do what I think it does, but that really doesn't matter in the end.

I attempted to look at the comments on `AudioHardwareSetProperty` but all I found was this in the discussion section:

> Note that the value of the property should not be considered changed until the
>                       HAL has called the listeners as many properties values are changed
>                       asynchronously. Also note that the same functionality is provided by the
>                       function AudioObjectGetPropertyData().

This is obviously not true, since I know for a fact that `AudioObjectGetPropertyData` is used for *getting* information about *one specific audio device*.

Is what I am trying to do possible with CoreAudio?

Comment: The docs you quoted presumably just have a copy-paste error. It should refer you to `AudioObjectSetPropertyData()`. Those functions are **not** just for one specific audio device, they are for modifying properties on any Core Audio device, including the system object (`kAudioObjectSystemObject`). See [Technical Note TN2223: Moving Off Deprecated HAL APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2223/_index.html) for the details of how to replace uses of the deprecated APIs. As to whether or not the new or old APIs do what you want, you need to show the exact calls you tried.

Comment: @KenThomases After a while of reading through that documentation I found this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HALExamples/Listings/ConfigDefaultOutput_c.html, but it seems like the headphones and speakers are the same device (`Built-in Output`). Is there a not to use the headphones?

Comment: I'm not sure. It may depend on the specific audio hardware of the system. Or maybe Apple just made their drivers merge those two physical output devices into one to avoid the possibility of having the system continue to output to the speakers when the headphones are plugged in (unfortunately for what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: If you use HALLab from Audio Tools for Xcode from [Apple's developer downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=audio), you can explore what's happening. On my system, Built-In Output shows the "Data Source" as either "Internal Speakers" or "Headphones" and it switches automatically. Only one is available at a time. The notifications show changes to the `kAudioDevicePropertyDataSource` property, among others. (By the way, look to the CoreAudio framework headers for docs.) If you can find the owner of that, maybe you can change it, but I doubt it.

Comment: @KenThomases I'm pretty sure you can change `kAudioDevicePropertyDataSource` with `AudioObjectSetPropertyData`. The issue is, I don't know the id of the speakers, so I need to figure out what that is before I can set it.

Comment: You can set `kAudioDevicePropertyDataSource`, but I think only to one of the values from `kAudioDevicePropertyDataSources` (plural). That property is also changing and I suspect it changes from having just the internal speakers to having just the headphones. That's presumably why the pop-up for Data Source in HALLab only ever has one choice.

Comment: @KenThomases could `kAudioDevicePropertyDataSources` be modified first to add the new source?

Comment: I don't know, but from where would you obtain the ID to add? You can use `AudioObjectIsPropertySettable()` to check if a property is settable.

Comment: @KenThomases It's a shame, I think there were function in Admin.framework, but rootpipe got patched and now you can't connect with XPC without a special entitlement :P

Comment: It is annoying when I plug my Macbook into my dock connected to my Thuderbolt display. It keeps thinking I want to use the display audio, and not the headphones. At work this can result in some embarassing situations.